# Produce a Cartesian product with two lists in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have two lists in a terraform module...

```
cidr_blocks = ["1.2.3.4/32","5.6.7.8/32"]
```

and I have another list of settings for a network ACL

```
ingress_ports = [
    {
      from_port   = 80
      to_port     = 80
      protocol    = "tcp"
    },
    {
      from_port   = 443
      to_port     = 443
      protocol    = "tcp"
    },
    {
      from_port   = 22
      to_port     = 22
      protocol    = "tcp"
    }
]
```

and I want to join these lists together so I can then use the resulting list to create a network ACL.

```
result = [
  {
      cidr_block = "1.2.3.4/32"
      from_port   = 80
      to_port     = 80
      protocol    = "tcp"
   },
   {
      cidr_block = "1.2.3.4/32"
      from_port   = 443
      to_port     = 443
      protocol    = "tcp"
    },
    {
      cidr_block = "1.2.3.4/32"
      from_port   = 22
      to_port     = 22
      protocol    = "tcp"
    },
  {
      cidr_block = "5.6.7.8/32"
      from_port   = 80
      to_port     = 80
      protocol    = "tcp"
   },
   {
      cidr_block = "5.6.7.8/32"
      from_port   = 443
      to_port     = 443
      protocol    = "tcp"
    },
    {
      cidr_block = "5.6.7.8/32"
      from_port   = 22
      to_port     = 22
      protocol    = "tcp"
    }
]
```

Is this sort of thing possible in Terraform ?

Comment: I don't think you can generate that output exactly but you can trivially loop over the CIDR block list to create resources that have the values from the group of ingress ports. What's the wider thing you're trying to solve here? Is it creating AWS NACLs/SG rules?

Comment: I'm using the terraform-aws-security-group github module and i'd like to have something similar for ACLs. I just stumbled across this...  https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12517 which looks intriguing.  Maybe I could do what I want if I was to have a module call another module to create an inner and outer loop ?

Comment: My project requires juggling a lot of IPs and combining different groups of IPs into a network ACL.  Our team is very distributed across the globe and we use the network ACL to allow only the IPs that we want ( offices, customers, remote locations )

Comment: Why exactly do you need to use NACLs rather than just SGs?

Comment: We are working on a new architecture and are trying to leverage NACLs as well as SGs in the way that Amazon intended ( according to our interpretation. )  Our current architecture, the VPCs just use a jumbled mess of SGs. The NACL's ability to secure an entire subnet appears to be a valuable way to simplify our configuration.  In our new architecture, the NACL is the primary way customer IPs are white-listed into the VPC.    Although, I'm getting the impression that no one really uses NACLs ?

Comment: NACLs are a pain because they are stateless so they can very easily break stuff unless they're very wide in which case they're largely pointless in my experience. The only time I've found NACLs useful is for blackholing attacker traffic but that was before AWS WAF which is a much better way to handle that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In terraform 0.12, we can finally use [setproduct](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/setproduct.html) which makes this endeavor a lot easier:

```
cronjobs = [
  {
    schedule_expression   = "cron(5 0 * * ? *)"
    command_and_arguments = ["app/aws-console.sh", "task1"]
    description           = "Hello World"
  },
  {
    schedule_expression   = "cron(0 5 1 * ? *)"
    command_and_arguments = ["app/aws-console.sh", "task2"]
    description           = "Send Bills"
  }
]

environments = ["dev", "stage"]

locals {
  cronjobs_for_all_environments = setproduct(var.cronjobs, var.environments)
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "cronjob" {
  count               = length(local.cronjobs_for_all_environments)
  name                = "cronjob-${local.cronjobs_for_all_environments[count.index][1]}"
  description         = "${local.cronjobs_for_all_environments[count.index][0].description} (${local.cronjobs_for_all_environments[count.index][1]})"
  schedule_expression = local.cronjobs_for_all_environments[count.index][0].schedule_expression
}
```

Comment: Several years later, I stumbled across my old post, now trying to eliminate a null_data_source. Grateful that Terraform has added these features.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution I used
Below is your test terraform script

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "us-east-1"
}

variable "lista" {
    default = ["1", "2", "3"]
}

variable "listb" {
    default = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
}

resource "aws_eip" "eip" {
    count = "${length(var.lista) * length(var.listb)}"
    tags {
        Name = "test-eip ${count.index}. ${element(var.lista, ceil(count.index/length(var.listb)))}:${element(var.listb, count.index)}"
    }
}
```

to test run
    terraform plan | grep tags.Name

below is the output

```
tags.Name: "0. 1:A"
tags.Name: "1. 1:B"
tags.Name: "2. 1:C"
tags.Name: "3. 1:D"
tags.Name: "4. 2:A"
tags.Name: "5. 2:B"
tags.Name: "6. 2:C"
tags.Name: "7. 2:D"
tags.Name: "8. 3:A"
tags.Name: "9. 3:B"
tags.Name: "10. 3:C"
tags.Name: "11. 3:D"
```

## My usecase was to map multiple peerings to multiple route-tables (one per AZ/NAT).

Comment: Wow, very nice. It is much easier to do with two lists.  Let me know if you try it with two lists with embedded maps.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I came up with.  I remembered that there is a way to use modulo and integer division to perform what I wanted to do.  I did this for both ingress and egress but I will only show ingress.  To aid in the flexibility of using this in a module, I create the Network ACL outside of the module and pass it in.

[Example module on Github](https://github.com/gbonk/terraform-network-acl)

Variables:

```
variable "acl-id" {}
variable "offset" {}

variable "ingress-rules" {
  type = "list"
  description = "The List of Ingress Rules. Each item in the list is a map.  The Maps will be joined with the 'ingress-cidr'"
}

variable "ingress-cidr" {
  type = "list"
  description = "List of IPv4 CIDR ranges to apply to all ingress rules"
}
```

Locals:  I created these for some clarity.

```
locals {
  ingress-cidr-size = "${length( var.ingress-cidr )}"
  ingress-rules-size = "${length( var.ingress-rules )}"

  ingress-join-size = "${local.ingress-cidr-size * local.ingress-rules-size}"

  ingress-joined-rules-cidrs = "${data.null_data_source.ingress-join.*.outputs}"
}
```

Data:

```
#Perform a cartesian like join of all of the CIDRs to apply to all of the rules
data "null_data_source" "ingress-join" {

  count = "${local.ingress-join-size}"

  inputs = {
    rule-number = "${count.index + var.offset}"
    cidr-block = "${ var.ingress-cidr[count.index / local.ingress-rules-size] }"
    from-port = "${ lookup ( var.ingress-rules[count.index % local.ingress-rules-size],  "from-port" ) }"
    to-port = "${ lookup ( var.ingress-rules[count.index % local.ingress-rules-size],  "to-port" ) }"
    action = "${ lookup ( var.ingress-rules[count.index % local.ingress-rules-size],  "action" ) }"
    protocol = "${ lookup ( var.ingress-rules[count.index % local.ingress-rules-size],  "protocol" ) }"
  }
}
```

The Network ACL Rule configuration:

```
##########################
# Ingress - Maps of rules
##########################
# Takes a list of 'ingress-rules' where each list item is a Map with the following keys
#  action: ether "allow" or "deny"
#  from-port: a port number
#  to-port:   a port number
#  protocol: A string like "tpc" or "-1"
#  rule-number:  A unique value to prevent collisions with other rules
#  cidr-block:  The CIDR that is applied to this rule
resource "aws_network_acl_rule" "ingress-rules-and-cidr-list" {

  count = "${var.create ? local.ingress-join-size : 0}"

  network_acl_id = "${var.acl-id}"
  egress              = false

  rule_number     = "${lookup( local.ingress-joined-rules-cidrs[count.index], "rule-number", "")}"
  rule_action     = "${lookup( local.ingress-joined-rules-cidrs[count.index], "action", "")}"

  cidr_block     = "${lookup(local.ingress-joined-rules-cidrs[count.index], "cidr-block", "")}"

  from_port    = "${lookup(local.ingress-joined-rules-cidrs[count.index], "from-port", "")}"
  to_port     = "${lookup(local.ingress-joined-rules-cidrs[count.index], "to-port", "")}"
  protocol    = "${lookup(local.ingress-joined-rules-cidrs[count.index], "protocol", "")}"

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a different approach at below link -

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/6657#issuecomment-453304599

Same code snippet -

I was looking for the solution to concat two lists and found the solution using in below format -

```
locals {
  a_identifiers = [
    "arn:aws:iam::hhhhjjjjj:role/account_dev",
    "arn:aws:iam::hhhhjjjjj:role/account_stage",
  ]
}
locals {
  b_identifiers = [
    "arn:aws:iam::hhhhjjjjj:role/account_qa",
    "arn:aws:iam::hhhhjjjjj:role/account_prod",
  ]
}
locals {
  combo_identifiers = "${concat(a_identifiers,b_identifiers)}"
}
```

this is how I can use it after this -

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "access_policy" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type = "AWS"

      identifiers = ["${local.combined_identifiers}"]
    }

    actions = [
      "ec2:*",
    ]

    resources = [
      "*",
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope someone will find it useful

Answer (score 0):

@grbonk, I see what you are doing. Thank you very much for pointing. At first, it was bit hard to understand your code since it has your scenario specific resources and variables and also not having the variable values, could not see the output. But, re-reading helped and below is my sample code I hope someone may find useful. I am leaving my original post as-is so that readers can see the limitations of simple-list vs list-of-maps as you pointed out.

I learnt couple of things 
1. element() only supports simple-list (flat-list) and not list-of-maps
2. ceil() is implicit when division used as list index
3. learnt a bit about null_data_source

Here is the code

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

variable "players" {
  type = "list"
  default = [
    {name = "Paul Pierce" position = "Small Forward"},
    {name = "Kevin Garnett" position = "Power Forward"},
    {name = "Ray Allen" position = "Shooting Guard"}
  ]
}

variable "teams" {
  type = "list"
  default = [
    {name = "Brooklyn Nets" conference = "eastern"},
    {name = "La Lakers" conference = "western"},
    {name = "Miami Heat" conference = "eastern"}
  ]
}

variable "fit" {
  type = "list"
  default = ["good", "bad", "ugly"]
}

data "template_file" "trade_options" {
  count = "${length(var.players) * length(var.teams)}"
  template = <<EOF
  "$${optionid}. Trade $${player} ($${position}) to $${team} ($${conference}-conference) and its $${fit}"
EOF


  vars = {
    optionid = "${count.index}"
    player = "${lookup(var.players[count.index/length(var.teams)], "name")}"
    position = "${lookup(var.players[count.index/length(var.teams)], "position")}"
    team = "${lookup(var.teams[count.index % length(var.teams)], "name")}"
    conference = "${lookup(var.teams[count.index % length(var.teams)], "conference")}"
    fit = "${var.fit[count.index % length(var.fit)]}"
  }
}

output "trade-options" {
  value = "${data.template_file.trade_options.*.rendered}"
}
```

Following is the output when you run terraform apply|grep Trade

```
"0. Trade Paul Pierce (Small Forward) to Brooklyn Nets (eastern-conference) and its good"
"1. Trade Paul Pierce (Small Forward) to La Lakers (western-conference) and its bad"
"2. Trade Paul Pierce (Small Forward) to Miami Heat (eastern-conference) and its ugly"
"3. Trade Kevin Garnett (Power Forward) to Brooklyn Nets (eastern-conference) and its good"
"4. Trade Kevin Garnett (Power Forward) to La Lakers (western-conference) and its bad"
"5. Trade Kevin Garnett (Power Forward) to Miami Heat (eastern-conference) and its ugly"
"6. Trade Ray Allen (Shooting Guard) to Brooklyn Nets (eastern-conference) and its good"
"7. Trade Ray Allen (Shooting Guard) to La Lakers (western-conference) and its bad"
"8. Trade Ray Allen (Shooting Guard) to Miami Heat (eastern-conference) and its ugly"
```